# How to go back when a Stack Navigator is nested within another Stack Navigator? Without two headers appearing?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Pretty much the same problem everyone else has seemed to have but I have not come up with a solution.  When I nest a stack navigator there is two headers.  I can remove the nested header using { header: null } or even that header mode option.  Well the problem is,(which has been pointed out here numerous times https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/88), that this is the root header.  So there is no back button available.  How can I remove the root header and keep the nested header?  I'm able to pull something similar with a tab bar.  I do:

```
navigatorName.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
let tabBarVisible = true;
if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    tabBarVisible = false;
}
return { tabBarVisible }};
```

I tried doing this by setting header to null but it didn't seem to work?  Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is my code

```
const BatteryListStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
BatteryList: BatteryList,
BatteryDetails: BatteryDetailsBottomTabNavigator,
});

const RouteListStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
RouteList: RouteList,
BatteryList: BatteryListStackNavigator,
});

RouteListStackNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
let tabBarVisible = true;
if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
    tabBarVisible = false;
}

return {
    tabBarVisible,
};
};

const IndexBottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    Home: Home,
    RouteList: RouteListStackNavigator,
    Alerts: Alerts,
}
);

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
{
    Login: Login,
    Application: IndexBottomTabNavigator,
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
},
);
```

If I set it like this:

```
const BatteryListStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    BatteryList: BatteryList,
    BatteryDetails: BatteryDetailsBottomTabNavigator,
},
{
    headerMode: 'none',
},
);
```

It works on the way through but when I get back it disappears? Which I'm guessing is because its still the root one so on the third, the back button takes you all the way to the first...

I'm trying to set it in the sameplace I have the tabBarVisible.. I've tried header: null, headerMode: 'none'.  None of them seem to be working in that navigationsOptions function I am doing.

Edit: should I just set all subsequent headers after the first stack navigation to none and then just programatically set my back buttons based on everything?  I think this is what i'm going to do.

Comment: Please post code where you are nesting the stack navigators

Comment: Okay I did! It happens inbetween the BatteryListStackNavigator and the RouteListStackNavigator

Answer (score 0):

use this.props.navigation.goBack()

Answer (score 0):

What I decided to do was set all of the various stack navigators with the header: null like this

```
const RouteListStackNavigator = 
createStackNavigator(
{
    RouteList: RouteList,
    BatteryList: BatteryListStackNavigator,
},
{
    navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
    },
},
);
```

Then in each Screen I used the static navigationOptions available.  This is the basic layout that I used.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: 'Battery List',
        headerLeft: (
            <Button
                title="back"
                onPress={() => {

console.log(navigation.state.routeName);

navigation.navigate('RouteList');
                }}
            />
        ),
    };
};
```

This obviously isn't ideal.. If someone has a better suggestion let me know. I will try to make the button look like the native options. Probably work on a method so I don't have to manually set up the

```
navigation.navigate()
```

manually for each component.  Seems too easy to make a mistake.   navigation.goBack() doesn't seem to work, and you can't access 'this' from a static method so I don't think i'll be able to access the props..

I won't accept this answer just incase someone comes up with a better solution.

EDIT:

I did end up setting it so that if I

```
navigation.push.('Screen')
```

on a button to go to the next screen.  I can use

```
navigation.pop()
```

in the static navigation options method to bring me back to the previous location.  I am going to see how smooth this process works with adding parameters here shortly.